# How can I update my app's Live Tile Badge in WP8?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, badge

I hoped this code from page 549 of Nathan's "Windows 8 Apps with XAML and C#":

```
    //string xmlString = @"<badge value='2'/>";
    string xmlString = string.Format(@"<badge value={0}/>", 42);
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument(); 
    document.LoadXml(xmlString); 
    BadgeNotification notification = new BadgeNotification(document);
    BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication().Update(notification);
```

...would also work for WP8, but many of the classes are unrecognized in my WP8 ScheduledTaskAgent, namely XmlDocument, BadgeNotification, and BadgeUpdateManager.

How can I accomplish the same thing in WP8 from my ScheduledTaskAgent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The APIs for updating a badge on WP8 are different than those on Windows 8.  The badge value can be set using the [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.standardtiledata.count%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property on a [`StandardTileData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh203149%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) object.

The [WP8 Tile sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Tile-Sample-ef741c45/sourcecode?fileId=62821&pathId=110379512) on MSDN shows more detailed code.

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlDocument badgeDOM = new XmlDocument();
badgeDOM.LoadXml(string.Format("<badge value='{0}'/>", 42));
BadgeNotification badge = new BadgeNotification(badgeDOM);
BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication().Update(badge);
```

Comment: "<badge value='{0}'/>" - there are apostrophes ('), in the first post they are not